The cardinality of all sets $A$ such that $\forall \ z\in \mathbb{Z} \ , (z-k,z+k)\ \cap A=\emptyset : 0<k<0.5$
The question asks the following:
Given $k\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $0<k<0.5$ a set $A$ is "k-integer-avoidant" if $ \ \forall z\in\mathbb{Z}$ , $\left ( z-k,z+k \right ) \cap A=\emptyset$.
Let $B$ be the set of all "k-integer-avoidant" sets.
Show that $B\sim P(P(\mathbb{N}))$ for every $k\in\mathbb{R} : 0<k<0.5$
I have looked at the following example in order to understand better the question:
Suppose $k=\frac{1}{4}$.
Here is number of sets of the form $(z-k,z+k)\ :\ z\in \mathbb{Z}$ :
$\left \{\ (-2.25,-1.75),(-1.25,-0.75),(-0.25,0.25),(0.75,1.25), (1.75,2.25)\ \right \}$
Here is number of sets of "k-integer-avoidant" form:
$\left \{\ (-1.75,-1.25),(-0.75,-0.25), (0.25,0.75),(1.25,1.75)\ \right \}$
The only thing that this example helped to understand is that it might be wiser to work with a set of the same cardinality of $P(P(\mathbb{N}))$, let's say $\left \{ 0,1 \right \}^{\mathbb{R}}$.
I have came with the following injection $f : B\to \left \{ 0,1 \right \}^{\mathbb{R}}$ :
$\forall A\in B \ , f(A)=g(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix} 1 &x\in A \\ 0 & x\notin A \end{matrix}\right.$
Suppose that $A_1\neq A_2$ and w.l.o.g $\exists z\in\left \{ A_1-A_2 \right \}$.
Thus, from the definition of $f$ we get that $f(A_1)\neq f(A_2)$.
This gives me $|B|\leq |\left \{ 0,1 \right \}^{\mathbb{R}}|$
I'm not able to find an injection $f : \left \{ 0,1 \right \}^{\mathbb{R}}\to B$ or surjective $f : B\to \left \{ 0,1 \right \}^{\mathbb{R}}$ in order to finish the prove and I'm wondering if there a better way to tackle the question. 

For a fixed $k$, how does $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}-\sqcup(z-k,z+k)$ compare?

@Sloan Hello! I'm not able to evaluate $$\bigcup_{z\in\mathbb{Z}} (z-k,z+k)$$ (This is how I understood ⊔(z−k,z+k)) I tried to look at the example I wrote above but still couldn't see anything.

Fix $k \in (0,0.5)$, and for notation write $(z-k,z+k)=V_k(z)$. Now you're asking about the set $B=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}-\sqcup_{z \in \mathbb{Z}}V_k(z))$.
Notice $\mathbb{R}-\sqcup_{z \in \mathbb{Z}}V_k(z) = \sqcup_{z \in \mathbb{Z}} [z+k, z+1-k]$. Writing $\mathbb{R} = \sqcup_{z \in \mathbb{Z}} (z, z+1]$, I will let you justify that for each integer $z$ there is a bijection between $[z+k, z+1-k]$ and $(z,z+1]$. Use these bijections to show there is a bijection between $\mathbb{R} = \sqcup_{z \in \mathbb{Z}} (z, z+1]$ and $\sqcup_{z \in \mathbb{Z}} [z+k, z+1-k]=\mathbb{R}-\sqcup_{z \in \mathbb{Z}}V_k(z)$. Now the result follows from the fact that $|\mathbb{R}|=|\mathbb{R}-\sqcup_{z \in \mathbb{Z}}V_k(z))|$ and $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})|=|\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))|.$

Thank you very much for the answer. It took me quite some time to digest it. It is really beautiful. May I ask how did you came up with the solution?

Very informally, my thinking was that $\mathbb{R} -$"small balls about each integer" is really not that different than $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}$, which is known to be equinumerous with $\mathbb{R}$.
